# Запуск сервиса при старте аппарата

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать старт сервиса при запуске девайса. Перепробовал много способов, но они не работают. Мой манифест:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ua.intsystems.screenturn"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"> <!--If the app is on SD-->
   <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> <!--For some devices-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".ScreenOnService" android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

OnBootReceiver.class:

```
    public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final String LOG_TAG = "Logs: ";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ScreenOnService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Выполнилось",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

В манифесте пробовал указывать полный путь к классам - тоже не помогло, пробовал запускать вот с этим параметром и без него: `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` - тоже безрезультатно.

Comment: Под "не работает" вы что понимаете? Тут телепатов нет, поясните. Варианты прилагаю: "приложение не запускается", "запускается, но падает", "не вызывается ресивер при включении аппарата", "не вызывается сервис из ресивера" etc.

Comment: Не вызывается ресивер при включении аппарата, ну а вызов сервиса из ресивира тогда не получается проверить ))

Comment: Странно, что не работает. У меня аналогичный приведённому код работает...

Comment: @Kl0nLutiy, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235195/3212712), пишут что надо после установки приложения хотя бы раз его вручную запустить, чтобы начали отрабатываться случатели загрузки. Типа надо "ForceStop" в инфо приложения нажать, потом запустить. После этого при запуске телефона должно всё работать.