# Не работает автозапуск сервиса при загрузке телефона

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Не получается настроить автозапуск сервиса при загрузке телефона. BroadcastReceiver просто не отрабатывает.

В манифесте:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true"
          android:label="MyReceiver"
          android:process=":myreceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Код ресивера

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("======MyReceiver=======", "------onReceive-----");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

После установки перед перезагрузкой запускал, тестировал приложение, как сказано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/391667/201305)

Пробовал добавлять другие интент-фильтры:

```
<action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
<action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.SCREEN_ON" />
<action android:name="com.example.andrey.myapplication.TEST" />
```

От прочих системных событий ресивер тоже не срабатывает. Зато вполне успешно запускается при вызове из другого приложения таким кодом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction("com.example.andrey.myapplication.TEST");  
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что вы не добавили разрешения в манифест или не в том месте (не на том уровне) поместили в него тег ресивера. Приведите манифест целиком. (можно вырезать оттуда активити, сервисы)

Comment: Проблема действительно в заглавных буквах, которые студия, кстати, сама подставляет. Когда начинаешь писать имя фильтра - если набираешь "BOOT" - студия автоматом подставляет имя с большими буквами. Если набирать "boot" - подставит правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю ,что проблема в заглавных буквах. `action name` на самом деле должен выглядеть, как

```
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно надо не капсом писать, а вот так: `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`